# Get Android ICS data usage, soft and hard limit programmatically

Tags: android, android-widget

Since Android ICS, you can set your mobile data usage limits. You are able to set a soft and a hard data usage limit. This is located under settings -> data usage This screen also shows you the amount of data used for this month.

I would like to show this data in a widget but I am unable to find how to get the:

- data used this month
- mobile data soft limit
- mobile data hard limit

I found [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html) but this does not look like the right code.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this question? I am after the same thing.

Comment: I have same need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366016/how-to-get-programmatically-the-data-usage-limit-set-by-user-on-android-os-confi

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html

That should solve your problems

Comment: Thanks, but this API does not provide data range and also does not provide the hard and soft limits set by the user.

Comment: I have same need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366016/how-to-get-programmatically-the-data-usage-limit-set-by-user-on-android-os-confi