# How to get programmatically the data usage limit set by user on Android OS configuration?

Tags: android, android-download-manager, network-traffic, user-preferences, android-settings

User can define at Data Usage screen a limite and/or a warning limit for mobile data usage. So how can I get this information by code?

Screen of Data Usage configuration of native OS.

[image: Data usage OS system configuration screen]

I wanna the limit value and warning value.

I've already tried this but not work and always return NULL to both:

```
final Long recommendedBytes = DownloadManager.getRecommendedMaxBytesOverMobile( this.context );
final Long maximumBytes = DownloadManager.getMaxBytesOverMobile( this.context );

// recommendedBytes and maximumBytes are NULL
```

And [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) class just have a data transferred not the limits.

Comment: Did you set the `INTERNET` permissions?

Comment: @Manu Yes and more... I tryed with all this: INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, READ_SYNC_SETTINGS. Some no make sense but I tried all I thought.

Comment: @xpto did you get any workaround solution? Me also facing the same problem, but for me NetworkPolicyManager is made hidden is an issue and I can't find any public API for same.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After days searching and research about this problem I couldn't find a answer for that. Bellow I will lift every attempt that I did.

**1. [Download Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)**

> With this class you can start download over any network or device
>   state and it will handle all states e.g. network loss, device reboot,
>   etc...
>
> There are two methods called [`getMaxBytesOverMobile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#getMaxBytesOverMobile(android.content.Context)) and
>   [`getRecommendedMaxBytesOverMobile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#getRecommendedMaxBytesOverMobile(android.content.Context)), they was a pretty candidate
>   to solve this problem at first time. But after code tests and
>   [Download Manager implementantion](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/app/DownloadManager.java?av=f) research I'd found that there is
>   no way to get thoose values by DownloadManager.
>
> **Reason**
>
> Thoose methods call [`Settings.Secure.getLong`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/provider/Settings.java#Settings.Secure.getLong%28android.content.ContentResolver%2Cjava.lang.String%29) with they
>   respective labels
>   [`Settings.Secure.DOWNLOAD_MAX_BYTES_OVER_MOBILE`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/provider/Settings.java#Settings.Secure.0DOWNLOAD_MAX_BYTES_OVER_MOBILE) and
>   [`Settings.Secure.DOWNLOAD_RECOMMENDED_MAX_BYTES_OVER_MOBILE`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/provider/Settings.java#Settings.Secure.0DOWNLOAD_RECOMMENDED_MAX_BYTES_OVER_MOBILE) in
>   the turn makes a call to a lazy [`String`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/lang/String.java#String) map inside inside a
>   inner class called [`NameValueCache`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/provider/Settings.java#Settings.NameValueCache).
>
> Ok so far but none of inner classes or `Settings` implementation it
>   self use `DOWNLOAD_MAX_BYTES_OVER_MOBILE` or
>   `DOWNLOAD_RECOMMENDED_MAX_BYTES_OVER_MOBILE` inside.
>
> I considered the lazy map was populate by a third entity, what
>   actually happens, so I found the [`NameValueTable`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/provider/Settings.java#Settings.NameValueTable) `Settings`
>   inner class that handle the new values to lazy map. The
>   [`putString`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/provider/Settings.java#Settings.NameValueTable.putString%28android.content.ContentResolver%2Candroid.net.Uri%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29) is a `protected` method call by `Settings.Secure`
>   and `Settings.System` inner classes (calls of [Secure](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/provider/Settings.java#2219) and
>   [System](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/provider/Settings.java#835)).
>
> **So I could conclude that if the OS implementantion do not put thoose String values I can't get them.**

**2. [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html)**

> Just a quick look on official reference I could notice that it will
>   not help me because this class just provide the amount of bytes and
>   packages that was trafficked since last device boot.
>
> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html

**3. [NetworkPolicyManager and NetworkPolicy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24445424/575643)**

> As @bina posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24445424/575643) the both classes are hidden and could not
>   be use by normal apps e.g. that will be published in Google Play.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/24445424/575643

**4. [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)**

> In short, you just can get the [`NetworkInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html) that not provide
>   much information about user preferences (really none!). Just provide
>   informations about network and e.g. mobile network provider.
>
> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

After all I assume that no way to get this information nowadays. Please if you read it and found a way post here!

Thanks for all.

*PS.: Sorry by english mistakes.*

Answer (score 11):

Do you want to get limit value(5GB) and warnning value(2GB) in this example?

If so, you can get limitBytes and warningBytes by the following code, if you can use android.permission.MANAGE_NETWORK_POLICY and android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
However, android.permission.MANAGE_NETWORK_POLICY protectionLevel is signature.

```
NetworkPolicyManager manager = (NetworkPolicyManager) getSystemService("netpolicy");
NetworkPolicy[] networkPolicies = manager.getNetworkPolicies();
Log.d("NetworkPolicy", "limitBytes is " + networkPolicies[0].limitBytes);
Log.d("NetworkPolicy", "warningBytes is " + networkPolicies[0].warningBytes);
```

(NetworkPolicyManager and NetworkPolicy classes are hidden)

Comment: Thanks @bina, I've tried this too but I need this value to general apps not especially kinds. With reflection I can invoke the NetworkPolicyManager easily but I need setup the permission that you notice, so it's became a problem again.

Comment: It is so painful that NetworkPolicyManager is a hidden class :(

Comment: This code is now deprecated in android 11 as it's a Non-Sdk API and Android marked it as a hidden api