# How to limit the internet speed of a network in android device

Tags: android, bandwidth, android-networking

I am searching for an API which could limit the internet download speed by lowering the bandwidth of the connection. Is it possible to do this without root privileges android?

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366016/how-to-get-programmatically-the-data-usage-limit-set-by-user-on-android-os-confi

Comment: @Satyavrat Thanks but I need to work with network's bandwidth. Something like an app in play store, by name "Brandy bound". but without "su" commands. Is there any API from google or any other source[except for rooting]?

Answer (score 0):

you can get limitBytes and warningBytes by the following code, if you can use `android.permission.MANAGE_NETWORK_POLICY` and `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`.
However, the protection level of `android.permission.MANAGE_NETWORK_POLICY` is signature.

```
NetworkPolicyManager manager = (NetworkPolicyManager) getSystemService("netpolicy");
NetworkPolicy[] networkPolicies = manager.getNetworkPolicies();
Log.d("NetworkPolicy", "limitBytes is " + networkPolicies[0].limitBytes);
Log.d("NetworkPolicy", "warningBytes is " + networkPolicies[0].warningBytes);
```

(NetworkPolicyManager and NetworkPolicy classes are hidden classes)

Comment: How do I acces those hidden classes with reflection. Give a little hint please. Thank you.

Comment: somthing like this -manager = NetworkPolicyManager.from(context);

Comment: hi,do you have any sample.