# Set data limit / data warning using tasker or shell

Tags: android, networking, warnings, limit

I would like to adjust data limit and warning with tasker (if necessary with shell - I got root)

I found this thread [How to get programmatically the data usage limit set by user on Android OS configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366016/how-to-get-programmatically-the-data-usage-limit-set-by-user-on-android-os-confi) which does not give a solution and has a slightly different question (reading instead of writing data limit/warning)

Can someone tell me how to achieve that within tasker? The above looks promising but a) I don't know how to get that into tasker and b) do I really need to give tasker the mentioned permissions? Or which app would need those? I did that before and would find a way to grant that permissions.

Besides reading the data as mentioned above: I would love to have a way to adjust the limit/warning. How would that be possible?

BTW: I am using Oreo 8.1 Resurrection remix on a Asus Zenfone Selfie (zoot)

Comment: Isn't the stock system settings enough for this?

Comment: well ... I would like to automatically adjust the limit every day to avoid using more % of data than % of month has passed. I regularly overuse data because my wifi is off and I do not realize that my phone is connected via mobile data. Therefore I would like to have a data limit of 1/30th per day, increasing day by day which makes so much sense to me that I would love to see that in some custom ROM

Comment: Very interesseting ROM-wise feature. Upvoted.

Comment: nice to read that - I posted it here: http://forum.resurrectionremix.com/ but nobody seems to care ... maybe RR has a better place to put feature suggestions?

Comment: Explore AOSP, look at the stock limit implementation then try to programmatically override the settings. I'm not even sure you can achieve that without building your own ROM because those settings are protected I believe. Anyway, you'll have a lot of work to do. And if this is a feature request, then StackOverflow is not the place for it.